Route all traffic through Wireguard
I'm running a very simple setup one server and client.
Wireguard is hosted in two server have multi public IPs.
I want to route all traffic from client over Wireguard server.
Client --> WG Server --> Internet
WG Server
[Interface]
PrivateKey = 
Address = 10.0.0.1/22, fd10:8:0:1::1/64
ListenPort = 51820

# Client 1
[Peer]
PublicKey = 
AllowedIPs = 10.0.0.2/32, fd10:8:0:1::2/128

net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
net.ipv6.conf.all.forwarding=1
iptables -A FORWARD -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i wg+ -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE

Client
[Interface]
PrivateKey = 
Address = 10.0.0.2/22, fd10:8:0:1::2/64

[Peer]
PublicKey = 
Endpoint = publicip:51820
AllowedIPs = 10.0.0.1/32, fd10:8:0:1::1/128

The problem, if i set in AllowedIPs 10.0.0.x i don't have internet traffic over the tunnel but can ping over tunnel 10.0.0.0/22. If i change AllowedIPs 0.0.0.0/0 and start Wireguard client immediately i lost connection over WG client server, in WG server i can ping 10.0.0.2 so means there is a connection the problem is i lost connection WG client public IP.
What i want is, i can still connect to the system from outside of the tunnel when it is connected and route the other traffic in wg0 interface.
Also, client is going to host some services, http, ftp, db etc and this is going to bind wg0 interface, so when is connected public ip on WG Server reach client services.
I not know is possible to host services in client server.
Thanks for you help.

Perhaps you want AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/1, 128.0.0.0/1, ::/1, 8000::/1

That is what I wanted to say, but you were faster. In fact, that will solve the problem in 99% of cases with the same issue.
